# Unique identifier per wcf call

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I have wcf service in which I want to identify a wcf call by some identifier. OperationContext.Current.Incoming.  MessageId is the option in case of wshttpbinding. But I am using basic http binding. Suggest me other field as identifier. How can I get such unique identifier per wcf call using basic http binding?

Comment: What do you want to achive? If you tell us a little bit about the purpose, it may be simpler to suggest sometging.

Comment: I want to use that field to  store object in global dictionary and  access same object through out the call. Basically I want to maintain the lifetime of  a object per wcf call. Also I want to use that identifier for call tracing.

Comment: Do you want to maintain the "state" over several or you just a single call? If the first is the case, then a session may be what you're looking for.

Comment: I want to maintain a state  for  a single call

Comment: @klr - OP already said they were limited to used basic http. This does not support WS-ReliableSession.

Comment: Can the caller just pass a token in the call header or something?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to enforce caller to pass token in header. You can suggest me any other way which includes changes in application and not in caller.